# wrong result in java with sqlite using having

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, having

I have a table with following data

```
taskid   bind_address           type_id
1        tcp://10.10.1.2:8001   3
1        tcp://127.0.0.1:8000   2
2        tcp://10.10.1.2:8003   3
2        tcp://127.0.0.1:8002   2
3        tcp://10.10.1.2:8005   3
3        tcp://127.0.0.1:8004   2
4        tcp://10.10.1.3:8007   3
4        tcp://127.0.0.1:8006   2
5        tcp://10.10.1.4:8009   3
5        tcp://127.0.0.1:8008   2
6        tcp://10.10.1.4:8011   3
6        tcp://127.0.0.1:8010   2
7        tcp://10.10.1.5:8011   3
7        tcp://127.0.0.1:8012   2
```

with this sqlStatement

```
select task_id, bind_address,type_id 
From task_pub tp    
join task t   
    on tp.task_id=t.id  
join host h                          
    on t.host_id=h.id   
where h.id=3                      
group by h.id, task_id      
having min(type_id);
```

Per task I want to get just the row with the lowest type_id
If I execute this statement with sqlite3 I get this as result

```
2        tcp://127.0.0.1:8002   2
5        tcp://127.0.0.1:8008   2
6        tcp://127.0.0.1:8010   2
```

but with java and the jdbc driver for sqlite I get this (wrong) result

```
2        tcp://10.10.1.2:8003 3
5        tcp://10.10.1.4:8009 3
6        tcp://10.10.1.4:8011 3
```

the sql statement in java is 100% right, I copied the statement in debug-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`having min(type_id)` is simply equivalent to:

```
having min(type_id) <> 0
```

Presumably, you want the minimum `type_id` for each `task_id`.  Here is one method:

```
select task_id, bind_address, type_id 
From task_pub tp join
     task t   
     on tp.task_id = t.id join
     host h                          
     on t.host_id = h.id   
where h.id = 3 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from task_pub tp2
                  where tp2.task_id = tp.task_id and
                        tp2.host_id = tp.host_id and
                        tp2.type_id < tp.task_id
                 ) ;
```

Comment: your example does not give the right result for me. Why do I get the perfectly right result when I execute this statement directly in sqlite, and the wrong result in java?

Comment: @user2071938 . .  The values come from *arbitrary* rows (as clearly specified in the documentation).  You might get lucky, but, for the most part, we don't want to depend on luck when fetching data from a database.  The original version was missing the condition on `host_id`, which I have added.

Comment: thank you that's it!
in the not exist clause you have a join which should not be there, I can't edit it because I have to edit at least 6 characters